# How would I go about storing words from a plain text file to an array using C++?

Tags: c++

I've been tasked with writing a C++ program that opens a text file, determines the length of each word, then produces output stating how many times a particular word length occurs.
I've figured how to open and read the contents of the file.

How would I take each word and store them in an array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void getFile(string);

void getFile(string filename)
{
    string array[2]; 
    short loop = 0; 
    string line; 
    ifstream myfile (filename); 
    if (myfile.is_open()) 
    {
        while (!myfile.eof() ) 
        {
            getline (myfile,line); 
            array[loop] = line;
            cout << array[loop] << endl; 
            loop++;
        }
        myfile.close(); 
    }
    else{
        cout << "can't open the file"; 
        system("PAUSE");
    } 
    
}

int main(){
    string fileName;
    while (true){
        cout << "\nEnter the name of a file: ";
        getline(cin, fileName);
        
        if (fileName == ""){
            cout << "Invaled file name, enter another!!!"<<endl;
            main();
        }
        else{
            getFile(fileName);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can avoid storing every single word, instead you can repeatedly extract a single word by doing `string one_word; myfile >> one_word;`. Find the size of it, find the total count of words for this size, increase that count by 1

Comment: `while (!myfile.eof() )` -> `while (getline (myfile,line))`

Comment: Unrelated but this code explicetly calls `main`. It is explicitely forbidden by the standard, and you have no reason to do so.

Comment: another (issue)? that the foward declare of ```void getFile(string);``` is useles because you define that right afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not store words in an array.
You only need to store the word lengths and how often each of them occurred.
If you have a guaranteed and low maximum word length you can even simplify by using an array where the length of the current word is used as an index. Init all entries with 0. Then count entries up when the corresponding word length occurs.